# what's the difference between a boiler plate and a template?

Tags: jquery, boilerplate

what's the difference between a boiler plate and a template? I thought it was the same thing. why wouldn't you just say "template"?

Comment: A [template](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/template) can help *generate* the [boilerplate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code); but it is the boilerplate that remains, not the template.

Comment: how is that question relevant to SO

Answer (score 19):

To put it simply,

- A template provides the structure and layout for a document.
- A boilerplate provides actual text and images.

Boilerplate is something you copy and paste and adapt freely. A template is rather handled in an organised fashion, never adapted but parameterized.

Comment: Agree. My 50 cents: it all stated with `templates`. Some had text in them (for "inspiration") and others did not. Later the "inspiration" text snippets was baptized `boilerplate`

Comment: Is it right that an example of a template is a Lorem Ipsum HTML page? Some languages use template as in .tpl which I believe is a boilerplate in context which adds to the confusion.